# Expressing many-one-many relationships in Cypher/Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying to create the following in Cypher (all names are made up, this is an example use case, not actual data):

**Programs**:

```
(po0:Program {name: "xxx"}),
(po1:Program {name: "yyy"}),
(po3:Program {name: "zzz"}),
```

**Benefits**:

```
(b0:Benefit {name: "happy world"}),
```

**Providers**

```
(pr0:Provider {name: "aaa"}),
(pr1:Provider {name: "bbb"}),
(pr3:Provider {name: "ccc"}),
```

How do I express the idea that each program gives benefit `b0`, but that benefit is provided by a different provider depending on the program. For example, program `po0` gives benefit `b0` provided by `pr0`. Program `pr1` also gives benefit `b0`, however, provided by `pr1`.

If I wired this up like:

```
(po0)-[:GIVES]->(b0)-[:PROVIDED_BY]->(pr0),
(po1)-[:GIVES]->(b0)-[:PROVIDED_BY]->(pr1),
(po2)-[:GIVES]->(b0)-[:PROVIDED_BY]->(pr2),
```

Then afterwards I loose the relationships between which program uses which provider to give `b0`.

What is the proper way to wire this up?

The best I can think of is:

```
(po0)-[:GIVES {provided_by: "xxx"}]->(b0),
(po1)-[:GIVES {provided_by: "yyy"}]->(b0),
(po2)-[:GIVES {provided_by: "zzz"}]->(b0),
```

but that seems strange to me, since then I loose the direct reference to the Provider nodes, resulting in having to do an additional query for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATED]

Suppose you added another node label, `Service`, which represents a specific `Provider/Benefit` pair. For instance, if you defined:

#### Services:

```
(s0:Service {name: "a"}),
(s1:Service {name: "b"}),
(s2:Service {name: "c"}),
...
```

... then you could indicate that a `Provider` provides a `Service` that has a `Benefit`, as follows. Notice that multiple `Provider`s can provide the same `Benefit`, and vice versa:

```
(pr0)-[:PROVIDES]-(s0)-[:HAS]->(b0),
(pr0)-[:PROVIDES]-(s1)-[:HAS]->(b1),
(pr1)-[:PROVIDES]-(s2)-[:HAS]->(b2),
(pr2)-[:PROVIDES]-(s3)-[:HAS]->(b2),
...
```

Finally, you just indicate the `Service`s that each `Program` uses. Notice that multiple `Program`s can use the same `Service`

```
(po0)-[:USES]->(s0),
(po0)-[:USES]->(s1),
(po1)-[:USES]->(s1),
(po2)-[:USES]->(s1),

...
```

Comment: I like that. My only concern would be, what if, say, provider `pr0` also provided benefit `b1`, but for program `po2`? The way you have it, a provider has to provide all it's benefits to a program, though it might actually only provide certain benefits. (I think it's the same problem I have originally, only in reverse.)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to complete the triangle and also link back the program to the provider. I.e.

```
(po0)-[:GIVES]->(b0)-[:PROVIDED_BY]->(pr0)-[:RUN_BY]->(po0),
(po1)-[:GIVES]->(b0)-[:PROVIDED_BY]->(pr1)-[:RUN_BY]->(po1),
(po2)-[:GIVES]->(b0)-[:PROVIDED_BY]->(pr2)-[:RUN_BY]->(po2),
```

Comment: I think this goes back to my concern with @cybersam's original answer, which is that with this setup, you loose the fact that `pr2` provides that benefit for `po2` but not for `po0`. I think @cybersam's got the right idea with creating the intermediary node